# Clojure reducer/map not working

Tags: dictionary, clojure, mapreduce

I've an algorithm as follows -

```
(defn max-of
[args]
(into [] (apply map #(apply max %&) args)))
```

which works fine.

`(max-of [[1 7] [3 5] [7 9] [2 2]])` returns `[7 9]`

It basically finds the maximum element on each position. 7 is the largest first element is the collection and 9 is the largest second element. However, when trying to use `reducer/map` from `core.reducers`, i get

`CompilerException clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (21) passed to: reducers/map`

So this does not work -

```
(defn max-of
[args]
(into [] (apply r/map #(apply max %&) args)))
```

Why?

**UPDATE**

my final code is

```
(defn max-of [[tuple & tuples]]
  (into [] (r/fold (fn
            ([] tuple)
            ([t1 t2] (map max t1 t2)))
          (vec tuples))))
```

Running a quick bench on it gives `Execution time mean : 626.125215 ms`

I've got this other algorithm that I wrote before -

```
(defn max-fold
    [seq-arg]
    (loop [acc (transient []) t seq-arg]
        (if (empty? (first t))
            (rseq (persistent! acc))
            (recur (conj! acc (apply max (map peek t))) (map pop t)))))
```

which does that same thing. For this i got - `Execution time mean : 308.200310 ms` which is twice as fast than the r/fold parallel thingy. Any ideas why?

Btw, if I remove `into []` from the `r/fold` stuff, then I get `Execution time mean : 13.101313 ms`.

Comment: guess it gives you this result without `into` because `fold` is lazy, so the reduction doesn't happen until the first usage of the result

Comment: also i think that the folding approach is much slower due to the parallel processing infrastructure overhead, which will probably be counterbalanced by the complexity of tasks provided. In your case the task is trivial. Moreover the `transient` approach is a great optimization, and probably it is the most correct one.

Comment: thanks for all the insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question **why** has already been given. So let's answer the next question: "what are you trying to do?"

According to how i've understood your goal (find maximum elements by the position in tuples) and to do it potentially in parallel (as you are trying to use reducers), that's what you have to do

```
(defn max-of [tuples]
  (r/fold (fn
            ([] (first tuples))
            ([t1 t2] (map max t1 t2)))
          ((rest tuples)))

user> (max-of [[1 7] [3 5] [7 9] [2 2]])
(7 9)

(max-of [[1 2 3] [3 2 1] [4 0 4]])
(4 2 4)

user> (max-of [])
nil

user> (max-of [[1 2 3]])
[1 2 3]
```

or even better with destructuring:

```
(defn max-of [[tuple & tuples]]
  (r/fold (fn
            ([] tuple)
            ([t1 t2] (map max t1 t2)))
          tuples))
```

**update:**
for large data you should optimize it and switch to using vectors

```
(defn max-of [[tuple & tuples]]
  (r/fold (fn
            ([] tuple)
            ([t1 t2] (map max t1 t2)))
          (vec tuples)))

user> (max-of (repeat 1000000 [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]))
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
```

Comment: thanks, that works. However, I get a stack overflow error when my data set is really large. is it loading everything in the memory?

Comment: how large is it? how many tuples it has? how long is every tuple?

Comment: it's got 420420 items. each item has 10 elements.

Comment: right you are it was my wrong. `rest` returns seq, which is unoptimized for fold. i'll update my answer

Comment: updated my answer, now it doesn't lead to stack overflow

Comment: sweet thanks. I put an update regarding the perf gain. I assumed that using parallel would speed up my computation but it really didn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92757/discussion-between-lightning-and-leetwinski).

Answer (score 3):

`r/map` takes `[f]` or `[f coll]` - so your `apply` approach won't work here

```
user=> (doc r/map)
-------------------------
clojure.core.reducers/map
([f] [f coll])
```

vs.

```
user=> (doc map)
-------------------------
clojure.core/map
([f] [f coll] [f c1 c2] [f c1 c2 c3] [f c1 c2 c3 & colls])
```

Comment: ahh.. thanks. any ideas how I can use r/map for my problem? i'm thinking i'll need r/reducer.

Comment: just to be clear - you want to find the tuple which has the biggest `int` regardless of first or second position ?

Comment: no. I want to find the largest elements in each position. So for  `[[3 4] [5 2]]` I'd get `[5 4]`. Since 3, 5 are the first elements and 5 is the larger one. Similarly for the last position it compares 4, 2. 4 get returned because it's larger

Comment: looks like he needs to make a tuple of (apply max firsts) and (apply max seconds).

Comment: yup. but i need it to be dynamic. i want to use the same function for `[[1 2 3] [3 4 2]]` or `[[1 2] [3 4]]` or `[[2] [6]]`

Comment: why do you want to do it with r/map + r/reduce ? it doesn't give you any profit& Probably you want to make it parallel? so you need r/fold for that